# creating dynamic objects for text field string in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, string, object

I have my view in angular js as follows,

```
<label class="control-label">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="config.name" />
<br />

<label class="control-label">versionSpecificApiConfig:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="config.versionSpecificApiConfig" />
<br />

<label class="control-label">schemaUrl:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="config.versionSpecificApiConfig.schemaUrl" />
<br />
```

I am doing this because I need to have config object structure as follows,

```
{
 "name":"string",
 "versionSpecificApiConfig":{
  "string":{
           "schemaUrl":"string"
           }
      }
  }
```

but am getting error "cannot set property for string in versionSpecificApiConfig field". please help me creating structure like this.("string" in structure refers to the respective values of the particular textboxes).

Comment: your object structure is wrong. try this : {
 "name":"string",
 "versionSpecificApiConfig":{
  "string":{
           "schemaUrl":"string"
           }
 }
}

Comment: how would this work?  input boxes are text, but your `versionSpecificApiConfig` appears to be an object.

Comment: @Jenny how can I achieve such object structure as you said. please help

Comment: @swaroop sg posted answer please check

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this ?

```js
var app= angular.module("app" , []);
app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', Ctrl]);
function Ctrl($scope){
 $scope.config = {};
 $scope.Print = function(){
     console.log($scope.config);
 }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="Ctrl" ng-app="app">
<label class="control-label">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="config.name" />
<br />

<label class="control-label">versionSpecificApiConfig:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="config.versionSpecificApiConfig.string.schemaUrl" />
<br />

<label class="control-label">schemaUrl:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="config.versionSpecificApiConfig.string.schemaUrl1" />
<br />

<button type="button" ng-click="Print()">Click to see object</button>
<br/>
{{config}}
</div>
```

Comment: almost the answer I am looking for. but "string" in the structure has to be value of versionSpecificApiConfig textbox value.

Comment: Hey thank you for your response, but the thing is I want structure you suggested in the first comment okay. versionSpecificApiConfig:{ "String" this has to be the value of versionSpecificApiConfig textbox. and then so on as you suggested.@Jenny

Comment: @swaroopsg my first answer before edit was as per my comment.

Comment: Hey that gives structure as, VersionSpecificApiConfig:{"string":{}} like this. what am saying "string" has to be value inserted in textbox.

Comment: yes.. that is same as i commented.. but wat you exactly want?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141324/discussion-between-swaroop-sg-and-jenny).

Answer (score 0):

I have tried work around for this and its works perfect, Please try it and let us known.

```
<form ng-submit="func(config)">
        <label class="control-label">Name:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="config.name" />
        <br />

        <label class="control-label">versionSpecificApiConfig:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="config.versionSpecificApiConfig" />
        <br />

        <label class="control-label">schemaUrl:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="config.schemaUrl" />
        <br />

        <button type="submit"> Save </button>
      </form>
```

---

```
$scope.func = function(Obj){
      var keyObj = {};
      var versionObj = {};
      var data = {};

      var key = Obj.versionSpecificApiConfig;

      keyObj['schemaUrl'] = Obj.schemaUrl;

      versionObj[Obj.versionSpecificApiConfig] = keyObj;

      data['name'] = Obj.name;
      data['versionSpecificApiConfig'] = versionObj;
      console.log(data);
      var Json = JSON.stringify(data);
      console.log(Json);
    }
```